# Xamarin Forms Maps y Pins

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hola tengo una aplicacion de xamairn forms que busca escuelas en un mapa, hasta ahora tengo mi mapa y un pin que puse yo de forma manual, la cuestion es que uso **Maps places** de google para encontrar otros lugares y trato de ponerlos en el mapa pero no lo consigo, tengo la sospecha de que podria ser  porque estoy usando un **foreach** y pues la misma variable para todos, alguien sabe puedo renderizar varios pin a los que llamo de esta api?

Esto es lo que tengo

```js
public partial class Map: ContentPage {
  public Map() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Look4Schools();

  }

  protected override async void OnAppearing() {

    base.OnAppearing();



    InitializeComponent();

    if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) {
      await DisplayAlert("Advertencia ! ", "PORFAVOR ACITVE SUS DATOS PARA CONTINUAR ", "Ok");


    }
    var pos = CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
    var lon = pos.Result.Latitude;
    var lat = pos.Result.Longitude;


    MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(lon, lat),
      Distance.FromKilometers(8)));


    var pin = new Pin {
      Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = new Position(lon, lat),
        Label = "Mi ubicacion",
        Address = "aqui se encuentra usted",

    };

    pin.Clicked += async(sender, e) => {
      await DisplayAlert(pin.Label, "" + pin.Address, "Cancel");
    };

    MyMap.Pins.Add(pin);
  }


  public async void Look4Schools() {
    var pos = CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
    var lon = pos.Result.Latitude;
    var lat = pos.Result.Longitude;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=schools&location=" + lon + "," + lat + "&radius=10000&key=MIAPIKEY");

    switch (response.StatusCode) {
      case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):


        string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < GMapsApiCall > (xjson);

        var x = json_;
        var xc = x.results.Count;

        if (xc == 0) {
          await DisplayAlert("Advertencia ! ", "No hay escuelas cerca", "Ok");

        } else {
          await DisplayAlert("Exito ! ", "Encontramos " + xc + " escuelas cerca", "Ok");
          foreach(Result r in x.results) {
            Pin pinx = new Pin {
              Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(r.geometry.location.lng, r.geometry.location.lat),
                Label = r.name,
                Address = r.formatted_address,

            };




            pinx.Clicked += async(sender, e) => {
              await DisplayAlert(pinx.Label, "The address is: " + pinx.Address, "Cancel");

            };

            MyMap.Pins.Add(pinx);
          }

        }



        break;
      default:

        await DisplayAlert("Advertencia ! ", "Error al cargar el mapa ", "Ok");
        break;
    }






  }



}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
  x:Class="App1.Map">
  <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" IsShowingUser="True">
    <x:Arguments>
      <maps:MapSpan>
        <x:Arguments>
          <maps:Position>
            <x:Arguments>
              <x:Double>23.6260333 </x:Double>
              <x:Double>-102.0194722</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
          </maps:Position>
          <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
          <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
        </x:Arguments>
      </maps:MapSpan>
    </x:Arguments>
    <maps:Map.Pins>

    </maps:Map.Pins>
  </maps:Map>
</ContentPage>
```

Este es mi modelo de la consulta que hago

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace App1.Models_
{



    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlusCode
    {
        public string compound_code { get; set; }
        public string global_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class OpeningHours
    {
        public bool open_now { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string photo_reference { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public PlusCode plus_code { get; set; }
        public double rating { get; set; }
        public string reference { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
        public int user_ratings_total { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    }

    public class  GMapsApiCall

    {
        public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string next_page_token { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Y asi es como se ve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo algunas de mis referencias

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins

Comment: saludos hermano, de casualidad ¿estás siguiendo algún tutorial?

Comment: hola fred estuve leyendo varios, pero no consigo mucho :s

Comment: Edita la pregunta y coloca todo lo que has revisado

Comment: Prueba a agregar los Pins directamente en la Propiedad `Pins` de Maps, algo como `MyMap.Pins.Add(new Pin {
              Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(r.geometry.location.lng, r.geometry.location.lat),
                Label = r.name,
                Address = r.formatted_address,);`. Si de esa manera te aparecen, veremos como agregar el manejador del evento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YA esta por si a alguien le sirve solo cambie latitud y longitud de lugar

```
foreach(Result r in x.results) {
        Pin pinx = new Pin {
          Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(r.geometry.location.lat, r.geometry.location.lg),
            Label = r.name,
            Address = r.formatted_address,

        };
```

y pum listo